# Is it possible to check dialog title and close it if it has a specific text in Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I haven't used linux shell before and there doesn't seem to exist anything like Python on these computers. I am using this command:

```
watch -n 60 myapp
```

which runs myapp every 60 seconds. But the problem is if there is no license, then it shows a dialog which halts the command until you close it.

Is it possible to read the title of this window and then close it if it has a specific text?

Or is this too much to do in linux shell? If so, how else can I achieve such a task?

Comment: Well, you can do something like that, but it would be at the process level. There is no direct shell command that will read any gui window title. It would more depend on the apps you are wanting to monitor starting, either under a known name, or created a known run (or pid) file you could check for. If you know it will run with either of those conditions, you can check for a named process (or pid file) and then display your warning and halt the running process (assuming you have sufficient privileges). Python runs find on Linux, why not use what you know?

Comment: Thanks I know python but this is work computer and they don't have that installed AFAIK. I just created an empty .py file and right clicked on it, I didn't see any run option, so I assumed there is no python on this computer.

Comment: What does this program do when it's working properly? Does it normally exit in less than 60 seconds? `watch` is meant to be used with programs that produce some plain text output and then exit. It's a strange idea to use it with something that creates a window.

Comment: ...if successful runs are silent while errors create a window then maybe you avoid that by running it with no `DISPLAY` variable. Add `env -u DISPLAY` to the start of the command and see what happens

Comment: @JoanVenge you may well have python installed. There is no guarantee that right-clicking on a file with `.py` extension will provide context options to run it (especially if you didn't make the file executable (e.g. `chmod 0755` after you created it). I don't know what OS you are running, but you can generally check (from an xterm or file manager) `/usr/lib/pythonX.X`. Where `X.X` will be e.g. `2.7` (for python2) or `3.5` (for python3).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I found that that python 2.6 is installed. Now I wrote a script that does what I want, but I don't know how to launch Konsole with a given command that will launch my app. I tried from subprocess import call
call(["Konsole", "-e myap"]) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess you are using KDE desktop, it is `'konsole -e myap'` (lowercase `'k'`). You can also use `'xterm -e myapp'`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am using centos. I did that just now but I was basically using an alias jj which meant "job -l -l", but doing this opens and then instantly closes the window. I have to do this so when I launch my app, everything is set properly.